# using jquery How to alter http parameters of an image src attribute after the image is returned in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, demandware

I am getting an image tag which looks like this

http://sits-pod18.demandware.net/dw/image/v2/aaen_s31/on/demandware.static/Sites-kerastase-Site/Sites-kerastase-master-catalog/default/v1349421867355/large/Styling/Construct/Mousse_Bouffant_1000x1000.png?sw=226&sh=226', sizingMethod='scale'); border:none;" ;="">

If I simplify this then the http strings for the image tags looks like this

```
http://sits-pod18.demandware.net/dw/image/v2/aaen_s31/on/demandware.static/Sites-kerastase-Site/Sites-kerastase-master-catalog/default/v1349421867355/large/Styling/Construct/Forme_Fatale_1000x1000.png?sw=350&sh=350

http://sits-pod18.demandware.net/dw/image/v2/aaen_s31/on/demandware.static/Sites-kerastase-Site/Sites-kerastase-master-catalog/default/v1349421867355/large/Styling/Construct/Mousse_Bouffant_1000x1000.png?sw=226&sh=226
```

There are lets say 10 -15 of these tags enclosed in a divs with a class="foo"

I am trying to alter the sw=226&sh=226 to sw=350&sh=350 using jquery.

How should I approach this? Unfortunately I cant alter the way the image is coming in the page. If I could do that then I would approach to alter the height and the width attribute of the image tag.

Let me know if this sounds confusing then I can try to prepare a fiddle to explain it. The tricky part is it has to work in jquery 1.3.2..which is totally nuts

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('.foo').each(function() {
    this.src = this.src.replace(/=226/g, '=350');
});
```

Comment: Hi Badger...I tried your solution too. Couldnt make it work. I have put together a fiddle with T.J s solution here 
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/djWbd/2/

Comment: @badger--I see what you did. Nice. But unfortunately I have to make it work on jquery 1.3.2 :-(...pretty sad but I wish I could just change the version

Comment: @soum, this code should work the same in jQuery 1.3.2. `.each()` has been around since jQuery 1.0. Which part of it doesn't work for you?

Comment: That was totally my bad. I forgot to add a document ready after removing the 1.9.1..it worked ! thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple string replacement:

```
img.src = img.src.replace("sw=226&sh=226", "sw=350&sh=350");
```

...where `img` is the `HTMLImageElement` in question.

To do a bunch of those with jQuery, you'd use `each`:

```
$("selector for the images in question").each(function() {
    this.src = this.src.replace("sw=226&sh=226", "sw=350&sh=350");
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution. I think I am missing something here. Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/djWbd/2/

Comment: @soum: Yes, your fiddle was missing jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/djWbd/5/ (there I'm using 1.10, but any version of jQuery is fine for the code above). Other than that, it was fine.

Comment: Yes..just realized that. I think its my bed time and not thinking very streetlight. Thanks again for the solution